# Change content on mousehover and Restore after mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV with some text, want to change the text on mouseover, and restore the text after mouseout. Like following.

`<div class="test">Text of Mouseout</div>`

`<div class="test">Text of Mouseover</div>`

I tried to do it like following, but the text change when mouseover but not restore after mouseout:

```
$(".test").hover(
  function() {
    var $original = $(this).clone();
    $(this).html("Text of Mouseover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).html($original);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.test").hover(

  function () {
       originalText=$(this).text();
    $(this).text('New Text');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).text(originalText);
  }
      );
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rEQJv/1/)**

```
​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work perfectly. May I ask one more question: Now I know in my code, removing the "$" in "$original" will solve the problem, but why the "$" make it wrong?

Comment: The `$` in the variable name `$original` is just a notation to indicate that the variable is intended to point to a jQuery extended object. It is completely optional. It should not cause issues by itself.

Comment: @user1787650 $ has got nothing to do here , its just the way of decalaring variable in jquery.

Comment: Thanks all! I fully understand now. The reason why my code is wrong is because I used .clone(), instead of .html() or .text(). If I have to use .clone(), then I should do it like @Matei Mihai said to define the varible outside the hover function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `$original` variable outside the hover function

```
var $original = null;
$(".test").hover(
  function() {
    if($original === null)
       $original = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Text of Mouseover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).html($original);
  }
);​
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZphtC/1/)

Comment: why -1? Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `$original = $(this).clone();` creates a clone of the object causing an additional element inside the original element on mouseout. What you need is `$original = $(this).html();`

Comment: I didn't inspect what he's doing.. I've just told him what he should do for using that variable in the mouseout method.. I've edited my answer but you gave me -1 for nothing..

Comment: @techfoobar Do you think that changing text is better instead of html.Just curious.

Comment: Depends on the need and the type of data. With `.html()`, the browser checks to see if there are any tags in the string and if so, create/render them inside the element. With `.text()`, it simply html-escapes everything and puts it in as plain text. So efficiency wise, `.text()` is better if the data is sure to be flat.