# Jquery: how can I store a variable inside a function, and use it outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change a text according to a mouse hover event:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.blog_post_container').hover(function() {
        var title = $(this).find('.blog_title').text();  
        $(this).find('.blog_title').text("READ MORE >");
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.blog_title').text(title);
    }
});
```

In the HTML: div.blog_title is inside div.blog_post_container.

The variable "title" was created inside the function called on mouse hover to store the blog title of that specific blog post. The idea was to use it later, when the mouse leaves the blog_post_container, but I cannot use it outside the function where it was created.

I cannot either create the variable before that function, because it will always return the title of the first blog post.

I know the solution is simple, but I'm just not finding it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152683/change-content-on-mousehover-and-restore-after-mouseout

Answer (score 2):

Store the title like this:

```
$(this).data('blog-title', title);
```

You can then retrieve it later with just a reference to the element:

```
var title = $('.blog_post_container').data('blog-title');
```

[`.data()` API](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var` to attach variable to window object

```
   title = $(this).find('.blog_title').text();
```

It's better if you define it before the document ready

```
   var title;
   //document ready code
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an overly complicated solution:

```
function rollOver(oElem, tHoverText){
  this.tHover=tHoverText;
  this.oElem=oElem;
  this.init()
};

rollOver.prototype.init = function() {
  this.oTitle = this.oElem.querySelector('.blog_title');
  this.tTitle = this.oTitle.innerHTML;
  this.initEvents();
};

rollOver.prototype.initEvents = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.oTitle.addEventListener('mousehover', this.changeTitle.bind(this), false);
  this.oTitle.addEventListener('mouseout', this.restoreTitle.bind(this), false);
};

rollover.prototype.changeTitle = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.oTitle.innerHTML = self.tHover;
};

rollover.prototype.restoreTitle = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.oTitle.innerHTML = self.tTitle;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
var blogPost = document.getElementsByClassName('blog_post_container')[0];

var b = new rollOver(blogPost, "Read more");
```

To retrieve the title text, use `b.tTitle`.